# Azure App Service - My Host file

Tags: azure, host

I published my app on Azure App Service.
I don't want to buy domain for now.
I just want to use my local Host file to connect to my Azure App with the futur domain I will buy.

I added an entry in host file:

ip.ip.ip.ip    mywebsite.com

But how could I configure my Azure App?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do that. Web Apps require a domain you own. More at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/

Answer (score 1):

This will not work. Azure App Services work on the basis of DNS Names. By adding the above entry in the host file, the record will reach the App Services Front-End Servers. However, they will not be able to map the domain name to a web app and this will result in a **404 error**.

You will have to map a domain name to your Azure Web App in order to get this working. This implies that you will need to own a domain name, this in turn implies that you need to buy a domain name. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an IP address, you can use a cloud service web worker role (probably with a reserved IP, if you don't want a dynamic IP) instead of an Azure web app.